# What happens in the background when you submit a class based view?

Tags: django

I'm using a class based generic view, specifically the UpdateView. I have other objects that I have currently which does CRUD as expected.

Now, I created a new object which also uses the generic class based views. My issue right now is that when I submit an update form, I can't exactly trace what happens when I press that submit button on an update form.

it is pointing to go on this url
**http://localhost:8000/order/question_update/**

but I don't have a question_update url that doesn't have a parameter. I have a question_update url that has a parameter at the end.

from my urls.py

```
path('question_update/<int:pk>', views.QuestionUpdate.as_view(), name='question_update'),
```

and also the success url is not pointing to the question_update url above.

How do I know what does the generic class UpdateView does when I hit the submit button? I'd just like to trace where it's getting the URL which I did not declared anywhere.

I did a text search on my codes and this url is not declared at all.

here are the other URLs

```
path('question_list/<int:file_id>/', views.QuestionList.as_view(), name='question_list'),
path('question_create_param/<int:file_id>/', views.QuestionCreate.as_view(), name='question_create_param'),
path('question_update/<int:pk>', views.QuestionUpdate.as_view(), name='question_update'),
```

here's my view for update function

```
class QuestionUpdate(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    login_url = 'login'
    model = Question
    form_class = QuestionForm

    def get_form(self, data=None, files=None, **kwargs): 
        kwargs['pk'] = self.kwargs['pk']
        return QuestionForm(data, files, **kwargs)

    def get_success_url(self):
        messages.success(self.request, 'Question updated')        
        obj = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        return reverse_lazy('file_status:question_list', args=[obj])
```

and this is my template

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% load bootstrap3 %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Create/Update</h1>
    <form id="question_form" method="post" action="." class="form">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {% bootstrap_form form layout='vertical' %}
      {% buttons %}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      {% endbuttons %}
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

here's my model as well

```
class Question(models.Model):
    file = models.ForeignKey(file, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    query_type = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    date_sent = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, null=True)
    date_completed = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, null=True)
    responsible = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    remarks = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.file.id)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('file_status:question_detail', args=[str(self.id)])
```

Comment: Please show the rest of the URLs, the view itself, and the template.

Comment: Aren't you using `router.register()` in your `urls.py`?

Comment: @hugo, no sir I don't use that.

Answer (score 0):

It appears some tags in the form should not be there in the first place. What I did was get back to the documentation in django projects and identify how it should be declared properly.

My form starts with this:

```
<form id="question_form" method="post" action="." class="form">
```

But it should only be this:

```
<form id="question_form" method="post">
```

I'm not entirely sure why action and class tags are causing errors on submit of an update form, if you know please enlighten me. Another weird thing is that I have those 2 extra tags on my other forms but it only happens to fail on the UpdateView for the question object.

Also this was patterned from cookiecutter django  crud.